# Tensorflow: Is preprocessing on TFRecord files faster than real-time data preprocessing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

In Tensorflow, it seems that preprocessing could be done on either during training time, when the batch is created from raw images (or data), or when the images are already static. Given that ***theoretically***, the preprocessing should take roughly equal time (if they are done using the same hardware), is there any ***practical*** disadvantage in doing data preprocessing (or even data augmentation) before training than during training in real-time?

As a side question, could data augmentation even be done in Tensorflow if was not done during training?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any practical disadvantage in doing data preprocessing (or
>   even data augmentation) before training than during training in
>   real-time?

Yes, there are advantages (**+++**) and disadvantages (**---**):

Preprocessing **before training**:

- **---** preprocessed samples need to be stored: disk space consumption* *(1)*
- **---** only a "finite" amount of samples can be generated
- **+++** no runtime during training
- **---**... but samples always need be read from storage, i.e. maybe storage (disk) I/O becomes bottleneck
- **---** not flexible: changing datset/augmentation requires generating a new augmented dataset
- **+++** for Tensorflow: Easily work on numpy.ndarray or other dataformats with any high-level image API (*open-cv, PIL, ...*) to do augmentation or even use any other language/tool you like.

Preprocessing **during training** ("***real-time***"):

- **+++** infinite amount of samples can be generated (as it is generated on-the-fly)
- **+++** flexible: changing dataset/augmentation only requires changing code
- **+++** if dataset fits in memory, no disk I/O needed for data after reading once
- **---** adds runtime to your training* *(2)*
- **---** for Tensorflow: Building the preprocessing as part of the *graph* requires working with Tensors and restricts usage of APIs working on ndarrays or other formats.* *(3)*

Some specific aspects discussed in detail:

- *(1)* ***Reproducing experiments*** "with the same data" is kind of straightforward with a dataset generated before training. However this can be solved (even more!) elegantly with storing a seed for real-time data generation.
- *(2)*: ***Training runtime for preprocessing***: There are ways to avoid an expensive preprocessing pipeline to get in the way of your actual training. Tensorflow itself recommends filling `Queues` with many (CPU-)`threads` so that data generation can independently keep up with GPU data consumption. You can read more about this in the [input pipeline performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/performance/datasets_performance).
- *(3)*: ***Data augmentation in tensorflow***

  > As a side question, could data augmentation even be done in Tensorflow
  >   if was not done <strike>***during***</strike> *(I think you mean)* ***before*** training?

  Yes, tensorflow offers some functionality to do augmentation. In terms of value augmentation of scalar/vector (or also more dimensional data), you can easily build something yourself with `tf.multiply` or other basic math ops. For image data, there are several ops implemented (see [tf.image](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/image) and [tf.contrib.image](http://%20https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image)), which should cover a lot of augmentation needs.

  There are off-the-shelf [**preprocessing examples**](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/preprocessing) on github, one of which is used and described in the [CNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn#model_inputs) (cifar10).

---

Personally, I would always try to use real-time preprocessing, as generating (potentially huge) datasets feels clunky. But it is perfectly viable, I've seen it done many times and (as you see above) it definitely has it's advantages.

Answer (score 2):

I have been wondering the same thing and have been disappointed with my during-training-time image processing performance. It has taken me a while to appreciate quite how big an overhead the image manipulation can be.

I am going to make myself a nice fat juicy preprocessed/augmented data file. Run it overnight and then come in the next day and be twice as productive!

I am using a single GPU machine and it seems obvious to me that piece-by-piece model building is the way to go. However, the workflow-maths may look different if you have different hardware. For example, on my Macbook-Pro tensorflow was slow (on CPU) and image processing was blinding fast because it was automatically done on the laptop's GPU. Now I have moved to a proper GPU machine, tensorflow is running 20x faster and the image processing is the bottleneck.

Just work out how long your augmentation/preprocessing is going to take, work out how often you are going to reuse it and then do the maths.